Issue of create low poly model with decimate modifier
I'm new in blender, here I try to convert a high poly model to a low poly model, the UV outline, the polygons look good, but when I put a texture on it, that show the UV inside is distorted ,not accurate to the source model in some place.
At below image, the left hand side is the original model and right side decimated low poly model.
Do this issue have any solution?


Here is another image that show the comparison between c4d poly reducer, orginal and blender decimate modifier.

Maybe unwrap again? Try the basic Unwrap option, or the Project from View?

I can't easily unwrap again, the model is a clothing model created from marvelous designer, that's complex and have many drapping, here just show a easy example for better look

I face this exact issue with cloth imported from MD often. Unwrapping is the answer. You can set UV seams from UV islands and also pin those boundary UVs to keep the shape. There is no actual problem that would arise because of mesh complexity here, that's irrelevant.

Sad, that's mean this one don't have a blender side solution.
